# How to reproduce actions in batch file

Tags: windows, windows-10, command-line, batch, batch-file

I was wondering if it was possible to reproduce through a batch file actions (not necessary reproduce but obtain the same result) that I made particulary on this example:

I got the icon (here of battle.net) on the notification area of the task bar on windows.

1. I right click on it, a mini menu open
2. I click on "Hearthstone" (again for the example).
3. Battle.net and Hearthstone open in windows in task bar

All I wanted to know is if there is a way to reproduce that with a batch file, it can be by reproducing exactly my actions or by finding the responsible commands to reach my goal and in this case how to get these commands?

[image: Battle.net Menu]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should be able to do this no probs.

Depending on how fancy you want it to be.. you *could* [use a script to launch it](https://pastebin.com/RHmK9j37) or a simple shortcut will do the trick if you are not worried about it already running.

1. Find your battlenet launcher exe file.  For instance `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Battle.net\Battle.net Launcher.exe"`
2. Create a shortcut to this file and right click on that shortcut, go to properties.
3. On the "target" line, after "battle net launcher.exe", add a space and `battlenet://WTCG`

If you go the script route, you will either need to add .VBS to your list of extensions for your [PATHEXT](https://www.google.com/search?q=pathext+edit) environment variable.  Then create a shortcut to the script.. OR create a shortcut to WSCRIPT.EXE and put the script path (quoted) as a parameter.

Try this in a batch file.  Fix the battch.net launcher path if need be.  If not work, up the timeout and try again.

```
    @echo off
    "C:\Program Files (x86)\Battle.net\Battle.net Launcher.exe"
    timeout 5
    "C:\Program Files (x86)\Battle.net\Battle.net Launcher.exe" battlenet://WTCG
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! However it’s not so simple as that, in fact I need to launch hearthstone through the battle.net launcher otherwise it won’t work :/ That’s why I post a specific question with the notification task bar app .

Comment: Answer updated.  Should work.  Sorry: :)  If you have problems with it, lets work this out!  We can get it working.

Comment: Thanks again! This method seems to work 5 years ago on some posts however, for me it just opens up the battle.net launcher without opening the game, and does nothing when my launcher is already opened. Maybe it doesn't work anymore or maybe I did something wrong

Comment: Still not giving up.  I just updated with a half a$$ed batch file.  If it works, I will re-work my answer so it isn't half assed.  Please try.

Comment: Thank you for your great involvement, I increased the timeout to 30 but nothing changes, I still have the battle.net launcher window that opens but not the game :/. Maybe the battlenet://WTCG command was removed